# angular custom validation directive does not show error on keyup event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am creating a angular directive for validation in that am using a template of input type text,am binding an key up event in which am validating the input field, am just using ng-show to print the error messages, its printing after two key up event occurs, but its showing the exact error in console, please help me to solve this issue, am pasting my [plunkrlink](http://plnkr.co/edit/MPG36To7ICyBac5oTcH9?p=preview)
my code follows

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('markdownEditor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
        },
        require:'ngModel', 
        template:       
   '<input type="text" ng-model="foo" required/>',     
link:function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl){

      ele.bind("keyup",function(){

var reg=/[0-9!@#$%^&*_(=+^\(*\)\-\{:<>?|;',\/\[\]\"\})]/;

var y=scope.foo;
console.log(y);
if(reg.test(y)){
  ctrl.$setValidity('c',false);
console.debug("not ok");
}
else{
ctrl.$setValidity('c',true);
console.debug("ok");
}

      });
}
} ; 
});

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating angular biding from, outside world of Angular. Angular doesn't run the digest cycle for those kind of changes. In this case you are updating scope variables from custom events, which doesn't intimate Angular digest system something has updated on UI, resultant the digest cycle doesn't get fired.

You need to kick off digest cycle manually to update the bindings.

```
scope.$apply()
```

Better you could also use `ng-pattern` directive here which need regx value, when your regx doesn't get satisfied it adds `ng-invalid-pattern` class to that element. On basis of the you could add CSS rule.

Also @paul trone suggested to use `$validators` which is also good way to go.

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/39DDdidltoQ7bIf5LG8b?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the built-in ngModelController $validators pipeline to validate, it will update the `ng-valid-` / `ng-invalid-` classes automatically:

```
...
// in the directive link function 
ctrl.$validators.c = function(input) {
  return reg.test(input);
}
```